# Python - I'm not able run RemBG program

Tags: python-imaging-library, python-3.9

I'm trying to setup [rembg github repository](https://github.com/danielgatis/rembg/) in my system but I'm facing issues
When running the statement `rembg i input.png output.png` I face the following error

```
PS C:\Users\Asad Kareem\Desktop\Happy Frog> rembg i input.png output.png                
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\asad kareem\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\asad kareem\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Asad Kareem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\Scripts\rembg.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\users\asad kareem\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\rembg\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .bg import remove
  File "c:\users\asad kareem\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\rembg\bg.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pymatting.alpha.estimate_alpha_cf import estimate_alpha_cf
  File "c:\users\asad kareem\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\pymatting\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pymatting.util import *
  File "c:\users\asad kareem\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\pymatting\util\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pymatting.util.kdtree import KDTree, knn
  File "c:\users\asad kareem\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\pymatting\util\kdtree.py", line 138, in <module>
    def _find_knn(
  File "c:\users\asad kareem\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\numba\core\decorators.py", line 219, in wrapper
    disp.compile(sig)
  File "c:\users\asad kareem\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 965, in compile
    cres = self._compiler.compile(args, return_type)
  File "c:\users\asad kareem\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 125, in compile
    status, retval = self._compile_cached(args, return_type)
  File "c:\users\asad kareem\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 139, in _compile_cached
    retval = self._compile_core(args, return_type)
  File "c:\users\asad kareem\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 152, in _compile_core
    cres = compiler.compile_extra(self.targetdescr.typing_context,
  File "c:\users\asad kareem\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler.py", line 693, in compile_extra
    return pipeline.compile_extra(func)
  File "c:\users\asad kareem\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler.py", line 429, in compile_extra
    return self._compile_bytecode()
  File "c:\users\asad kareem\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler.py", line 497, in _compile_bytecode
    return self._compile_core()
  File "c:\users\asad kareem\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler.py", line 476, in _compile_core
    raise e
  File "c:\users\asad kareem\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler.py", line 463, in _compile_core
    pm.run(self.state)
  File "c:\users\asad kareem\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler_machinery.py", line 353, in run
    raise patched_exception
  File "c:\users\asad kareem\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler_machinery.py", line 341, in run
    self._runPass(idx, pass_inst, state)
  File "c:\users\asad kareem\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler_lock.py", line 35, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\asad kareem\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler_machinery.py", line 296, in _runPass
    mutated |= check(pss.run_pass, internal_state)
  File "c:\users\asad kareem\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler_machinery.py", line 269, in check
    mangled = func(compiler_state)
  File "c:\users\asad kareem\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\numba\core\typed_passes.py", line 394, in run_pass
    lower.lower()
  File "c:\users\asad kareem\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\numba\core\lowering.py", line 196, in lower
    self.lower_normal_function(self.fndesc)
  File "c:\users\asad kareem\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\numba\core\lowering.py", line 250, in lower_normal_function
    entry_block_tail = self.lower_function_body()
  File "c:\users\asad kareem\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\numba\core\lowering.py", line 279, in lower_function_body
    self.lower_block(block)
  File "c:\users\asad kareem\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\numba\core\lowering.py", line 293, in lower_block
    self.lower_inst(inst)
  File "c:\users\asad kareem\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\numba\core\lowering.py", line 565, in lower_inst
    func(self, inst)
  File "c:\users\asad kareem\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\numba\parfors\parfor_lowering.py", line 64, in _lower_parfor_parallel
    ensure_parallel_support()
  File "c:\users\asad kareem\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\numba\parfors\parfor.py", line 4701, in ensure_parallel_support
    raise errors.UnsupportedParforsError(msg)
numba.core.errors.UnsupportedParforsError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: native lowering)
```

Can anybody help me with the issue?